# Why did Mary Watson say what she said at the end of "The Six Thatchers"?

Tags: sherlock

At the end of [The Six Thatchers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Six_Thatchers) (S4 e1 of the BBC TV series, aired 1st January 2017), Mary Watson said:

> Go to hell, Sherlock.

This occurs right at the very end of the episode.

Mary Watson hadn't indicated any particular animosity either during the episode or in previous episodes. In fact, she and Sherlock generally seemed to get on quite well, with her helping him out in cases, etc. It's even more confusing, given that she just gave Sherlock a (rather personal) case.

Why did she say this and what does it mean?

I thought perhaps it is simply be that she had deduced that he is the most likely cause of her death. But it still seems a bit odd and out of place.

Comment: It's a post-credit scene....I think that's the point.....it's a set-up for future episodes. Any reasoning is **purely speculative** at this point.

Comment: @Paulie_D "I _think_ that's the point" - sounds like you're speculating ;)

Comment: And that is why it's a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[We now know what she meant](http://tvline.com/2017/01/08/sherlock-recap-season-4-episode-2-the-lying-detective-sister/) via the events of “The Lying Detective” (s04e02):

> Remember that video Mary left for Sherlock last week? John found it, and realized **she instructed Sherlock to “save John Watson” by getting himself into danger**: “Go to hell, Sherlock. Go right into hell and make it look like you mean it.” And it worked!

Answer (score 1):

In which country Mary went before being found by Sherlock and John? Right, Norway.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hell,_Norway

Comment: I suspect you might be right but a **reason** why this might be the case would be prefered to a bare *guess*.

Answer (score -3):

She is a mercenary, Paid for by Moriety to do the job she done perfectly, The best way i can think of getting at Sherlock and destroy him. The only think I'm not certain of, is are they actually gonna both not be dead somehow

Answer (score -5):

This is my interpretation: to save Watson, he has to go through hell. Metaphorically, meaning: facing his own past and therefore 'dark secrets'. This goes together with theories claiming that Sherlock probably has or faces depressions quite often. To overcome them (and therefore become a better person -> able to help and support John who also faces a similar situation after the loss of Mary), he would actually need to see a therapist (which, by the end of the episode, he does). As Mary knows Sherlock quite well, she knows that therapy for Sherlock probably will be like 'going through hell'.